# Scrapy - run at time interval

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, twisted, pickle

i have a spider for crawling a site and i want to run it every 10 minutes. put it in python schedule and run it. after first run i got

> ReactorNotRestartable

i try [this sulotion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43661172/7132357) and got

> AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'run_spider..f'

error.

edit:
try [how-to-schedule-scrapy-crawl-execution-programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47552507/how-to-schedule-scrapy-crawl-execution-programmatically) python program run without error and crawl function run every 30 seconds but spider doesn't run and i don't get data.

```
def run_spider():
def f(q):
    try:
        runner = crawler.CrawlerRunner()
        deferred = runner.crawl(DivarSpider)
        #deferred.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
        #reactor.run()
        q.put(None)
    except Exception as e:
        q.put(e)

runner = crawler.CrawlerRunner()
deferred = runner.crawl(DivarSpider)

q = Queue()
p = Process(target=f, args=(q,))
p.start()
result = q.get()
p.join()

if result is not None:
    raise result
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to schedule Scrapy crawl execution programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47552507/how-to-schedule-scrapy-crawl-execution-programmatically)

Comment: Why not just set up a cronjob for it? simple

Comment: Is it possible to make the `AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'run_spider..f'` go away in the solution above? I would really like to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The multiprocessing solution is a gross hack to work-around lack of understanding of how Scrapy and reactor management work.  You can get rid of it and everything is much simpler.

```
from twisted.internet.task import LoopingCall
from twisted.internet import reactor

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging

from yourlib import YourSpider

configure_logging()
runner = CrawlRunner()
task = LoopingCall(lambda: runner.crawl(YourSpider()))
task.start(60 * 10)
reactor.run()
```

Comment: From personal experience, I've found that `LoopingCall` isn't well suited for "scraping every X times" problems because it might lead to the same crawls occurring multiple times, which might mess up results. It's better to schedule the next crawl using callbacks from `runner.crawl()`.

Comment: LoopingCall definitely will not schedule two calls concurrently - as long as you return a `Deferred` defining when your call has finished.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I know to do it is using a separate script to call the script containing your twisted reactor, like this:

```
cmd = ['python3', 'auto_crawl.py']
subprocess.Popen(cmd).wait()
```

To run your CrawlerRunner every 10 minutes, you could use a loop or crontab on this script.

Comment: Sorry, just realized you told you wanted to put it in python scheduler. I'll try to update this answer later.